# Vertically Aligning Text Using CSS

Tags: css, html, layout, css-float

In the following **HTML**, why is all the content appearing outside the `<footer>` and why is the text not *vertically middle-aligned*?

```
<html>

    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                margin-left: 20%;
                margin-right: 20%;
            }
            footer {
                text-align: center;
                border: 1px dotted black;
            }
            #foo {
                float: left;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
            #bar {
                float: right;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <footer> <span id="foo">this is some text</span>
 <span id="bar"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wgFpmlN.png"></span>

        </footer>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `line-height` property. Try setting its value equal to the height of footer. It will only work for inline elements, for block elements you need to play with margins.

Comment: This might be helpful http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/how-centre-align-text-or-content-vertically-css

Comment: If for some reasonst `line-height` is not an option (vertical space created by that height is not clicable), use `padding` for element. Alternativly define element's `height`. Just remember to make it `display:block` or `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have floats and no block or inline elements, have a look at the [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) hack. Or I don't know if it really is considered a hack.

IF you don't really feel like reading just add this to your css

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Amd add a `clearfix` class to your footer

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<footer>
    <span id="foo">this is some text</span>
    <span id="bar"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wgFpmlN.png"></span>
    <br clear />  <!-- you need to put clear here or do that with css-->
</footer>
</body>
```

You can check at http://jsfiddle.net/yGPKF/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this

in this example `footer` has `height` and `#foo` has `line-height` both are same.

```css
 body {
   margin-left: 20%;
   margin-right: 20%;
 }
 footer {
   text-align: center;
   border: 1px dotted black;
   height: 100px;
 }
 #foo {
   vertical-align: middle;
   line-height: 100px;
 }
 #bar {
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<footer> <span id="foo">this is some text</span>
  <span id="bar"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wgFpmlN.png"></span>

</footer>
```